# How do I show real IP in rabbitmq-server with haproxy

Tags: tcp, ip

```
listen rabbitmq_cluster
bind    0.0.0.0:5672
mode    tcp
option  tcplog
balance roundrobin
timeout client  3h
timeout server  3h
server  busappser5  192.168.0.249:5672 check  inter  5000  rise  2  fall  3
server  busappser6  192.168.0.251:5672 check  inter  5000  rise  2  fall  3
server  busappser7  192.168.0.231:5672 check  inter  5000  rise  2  fall  3
```

[192.168.0.1 is IP of haproxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4BWa.png)

I have tried 
first 
`option  tcplog
balance roundrobin
source 0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip`



second

`server s1  127.0.0.1:7000 send-proxy-v2`

third

`option forwardfor`

All don't work

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to show real client IP in rabbitmq management

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass on the client IP address in tcp mode to the servers you'll want to use [send-proxy](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#5.2-send-proxy)

```
frontend foo
   ...
   send-proxy
   ...
```

Comment: 'option forwardfor' ignored for proxy 'rabbitmq_cluster' as it requires HTTP mode.I need "mode    tcp"

Comment: Oops, updated with the tcp option for passing the client IP